# How to generate a Makefile from dtx // keeping the tab width

Tags: dtx, makefile, literate-programming, docstrip

For a complete documentation I would like to maintain and explain the Makefile within my `dtx`-file.

Two problems occur:

1. `docstrip` always adds an extension to the generated file (`\file{Makefile}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{make}}`)
2. The tab in the `Makefile` is not preserved and got erased 
   (`all:    [[TAB]]lualatex $(NAME).tex`)

This is my MWE:

```
%\iffalse
%<*internal>
\iffalse
%</internal>
%<*internal>
\fi
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
  \expandafter\begingroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*install>
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\nopreamble\nopostamble
\generate{
    \file{Makefile}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{make}}
}
%</install>
%<install>\endbatchfile
%<*internal>
\usedir{source/latex/\jobname}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.ins}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{install}}
}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
  \expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
  \expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\begin{document}
\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
%\fi
%\iffalse
%<*make>
%\fi
% \section{The Makefile}
%    \begin{macrocode}
NAME  = testfile
%    \end{macrocode}
% The default command
%    \begin{macrocode}
all:
    lualatex $(NAME).tex
%    \end{macrocode}
%\iffalse
%</make>
%\fi
\endinput
```

[image: Makefile]

## EDIT

After the first run in the terminal with `lualatex DOCUMENT.dtx` I get the makefile.
Then I cannot simply run `make` but have to type in `make --makefile=Makefile.tex` and get the error `*** missing separator.  Stop.`

Comment: I tend to write raw Makefiles for LaTeX documents

Comment: Sure, me too. But then I have to write all the comments in the makefile. As I wrote, this is purely for documenting reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the dtx code as posted there are no tabs (as the site changes them to spaces) but if I put tabs back in the Makefile section and modify the `.ins` to look like

```
\catcode9=12
\generate{
    \file{Makefile}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{make}}
```

Then tabs are written to the Makefile if I use `luatex` on the .ins. (The resulting file gets called `Makefile.tex` though. (Extensionless files are tricky in TeX)

---

So if you replace the spaces before `lualatex $(NAME).tex` by a tab in the file below then

```
luatex file.dtx
```

will generate `file.ins` and

```
luatex file.ins
```

will generate a `Makefile.tex` with tabs (at least on cygwin texlive 2018 luatex)

```
%\iffalse
%<*internal>
\iffalse
%</internal>
%<*internal>
\fi
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
  \expandafter\begingroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*install>
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\nopreamble\nopostamble
\catcode9=12
\generate{
    \file{Makefile}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{make}}
}
%</install>
%<install>\endbatchfile
%<*internal>
\usedir{source/latex/\jobname}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.ins}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{install}}
}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
  \expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
  \expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\begin{document}
\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
%\fi
%\iffalse
%<*make>
%\fi
% \section{The Makefile}
%    \begin{macrocode}
NAME  = testfile
%    \end{macrocode}
% The default command
%    \begin{macrocode}
all:
    lualatex $(NAME).tex
%    \end{macrocode}
%\iffalse
%</make>
%\fi
\endinput
```

Comment: ok, I could live with naming it to `Makefile.make` but where exactly should I put `\catcode9=12`. When I put it where you are pointing it to I get `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`.

Comment: @LukasCB I added full example